# Zapier/Trello Link Causing Duplicate Cards

Tags: trello, wordpress, zapier

I currently have a zap on Zapier which takes Formidable forms entries on my WordPress website and creates a card on one of my Trello boards with the entered details.

There are quite a number of fields and it seems to split the entry over 2 cards on Trello.

Is there a solution/setting that can force Trello and/or Zapier to create a single card only?

Comment: Does it split at the same point in every card?